# Data Conversion and Extraction

Tags: sql, reporting-services, type-conversion

My table has a field with nvarchar data type. The field includes alpha-numeric characters and dates. How can I extract date part from the field?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CAST` for date type conversion.

```
SELECT CAST(tstamp AS DATE)
```

`CAST` works exactly the same on most SQL engines (SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL),

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the data looks like. For example:

```
declare @field varchar(100)
select @field = 'text text 2000/01/01 text text'

select convert(date,SUBSTRING(@field,CHARINDEX('/',@field,0)-4,10))
```

If you know, that the date is stored in yyyy/mm/dd format, you can use code above - find the first slash, cut the string from position of the slash - 4 with length 10.

Be more specific, provide some example, tell us what sql server you use, and we can help you more.

Comment: This worked whenever the date is in mm/dd/yyyy format. I receive "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" error when date is in longdate format. Here are a few examples:

>February 29, 2016.  
>2/29/2016. 
>text text 2/29/2016 text. 
>text text text February 29, 2016 text text

Comment: @Anonymous If format is mm/dd/yyyy, then you substract 2, not 4 from the position:

`convert(date,SUBSTRING(@field,CHARINDEX('/',@field,0)-2,10))`

But if there are different formats, then this would be extremely long and complicated query... It can generally be achieved by these functions - `SUBSTRING` to cut the date out, `CHARINDEX` to find character which can identify the date and `CONVERT` or `CAST` to convert it to `DATE` or `DATETIME`. 
See the reference [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx ]

Comment: @Anonymous And You probably don't want to hear it, but first of all - one column should never contain data, which you need to access separately...

Comment: The field contains notes from students. All students don't follow the correct format so I am stuck with converting the data.

Comment: @Anonymous The application should manage this. Not the database. You will have to build that many queries, how many possible formats there are. Worst case is this "February 29, 2016" - to find this in a string, you need to list all 12 months and search them inside. And pray, that the name of the month is not contained somewhere else in the string... And what if there are two or more dates? ...
This can be achieved only by a very complex procedure.